# JavaScript asynchronous programming

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently, I began studying JavaScript, and I reached a topic about asynchronous coding, or some refer to it as *function parameter* or *callback* (node.js to be more specific).

I tested some stuff with it, but can`t get the idea of it. For example

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("HELO"); }, true);
```

will do nothing. Can somebody explain in short what exactly is the idea behind asynchronous coding and what are these callbacks, also a 3-4 line example will be appreciated.

Comment: Check out a tutorial, there are bunch of them!

Comment: question is too broad in scope

Comment: @nalply Like Carl said in his answer, the window object is not part of the node.js environment. You are executing that code in Chrome which has the window object.

Comment: duh, didn't see that the question was about node.js

Answer (score 5):

The code you have written requires the window object which is not a part of the node.js environment.

I recommend watching [ryan dahl's introduction to node.js](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ryan%20dahl%20introduction%20to%20node.js&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQtwIwAQ&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I&ei=zkwRT4nxCIvktQb_l5gG&usg=AFQjCNFXUM9W91ks8PpqeKBcbH0TBXYwBA)

Comment: From the video, "node is basically a set of libraries on top of Google's V8 engine to create networking applications [written in javascript]". The video is very, very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for replying. JS is kind of new to me so my questions may still be lame :)

Comment: It's not a lame question. And if you wanna learn more about javascript I really recommend Douglas Crockfords book http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742

Comment: I`ve found that book and I think that this book http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1593272820?ie=UTF8&tag=marijhaver-20&linkCode=as2&camp=1789&creative=9325&creativeASIN=1593272820 is good for JS too with Crockford`s.